# What is actual purpose of enum as function argument?

Tags: c, enums

Until now I thought if a function argument is an `enum`, then it can hold only the values defined inside the `enum`. But it proved wrong in my case.

Code:

```
typedef enum
{
    a = 0,
    b,
    c
} X;

typedef enum
{
    e = 3
} Y;

void fn (X var)
{
    printf ("%d",var);
}

int main()
{
    fn (e);
    return 0;
}
```

Function `fn()` accepted the value e and its output was 3. Why does it happen?

Comment: Put the language you are using to question tags. Enums are common to many languages and appropriate tag will bring attention of experts in the language you are interested in. And such tag will also add a nice formatting to your code.

Answer (score 3):

Any integer value can be used where an enum is required. The compiler does not validate the integer values.

They are basically a convenient way to assign meaningful names to what would otherwise appear as arbitrary numbers in your code.